# can not compile OpenWrt-HiLink-HLK-RM04

Tags: makefile, embedded-linux

I going to run `OpenWrt` on `HiLink-HLK-RM04` but I get the following error:

```
checking for autogen... autogen
checking for inline... inline
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for getrandom... no
checking for getentropy... no
checking for NETTLE... no
configure: error: 
  ***
  *** Libnettle 3.1 was not found.
```

I searched, but could not find something helpful.
When I type `rpm -q nettle` I get the following result:

```
nettle-2.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

here is NETTLE section of config.log :

```
configure:8478: checking for NETTLE
configure:8486: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "nettle >= 3.1"
Package nettle was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `nettle.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'nettle' found
configure:8489: $? = 1
configure:8504: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "nettle >= 3.1"
Package nettle was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `nettle.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'nettle' found
configure:8507: $? = 1
No package 'nettle' found
configure:8535: result: no
configure:8538: error: 
  ***
  *** Libnettle 3.1 was not found.
```

Comment: Is there a `nettle-dev` or `nettle-devel` package available?

Comment: yes, rpm -q nettle-devel :::
nettle-devel-2.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64

Comment: Find the section in `config.log` which is trying to find `NETTLE` and see what it says it did and what failed. `config.log` is likely big and ugly and possibly hard to understand so you can just post the section about `NETTLE` here if that is easier.